# pyautogui doesn't press keys on pc startup

Tags: python, startup, keypress, pyautogui

I have been making a telegram bot that constantly runs on my computer. I made this project to run on pc startup using .bat file, so this bot starts working every time I turn on my PC and works until I turn it off. In my project I have some functions that press different keys, for example:

```
def simulate_key():
   pyautogui.press("f")
```

I can call this functions from my phone using telegram bot. Like I press on a button and this function is being called. Everything works perfectly, if I set the project to run from IDE or from .bat file (the same .bat file that runs this project on pc startup, let's call this .bat file "bot_start.bat"). In other words: project runs successfully from IDE and from bot_start.bat file (launched by me) and this function does what it is supposed to do, it presses "f", everything's cool. But the issue is that if the bot is launched from pc startup, then pressing "f" key doesn't work. However, everything else works perfectly. I've come to the conclusion that pyautogui and different libs (PyDirectInput) for some reason do not simulate pressing keys on pc startup, but only when the project is launched by me (from IDE or if I launched bot_start.bat by myself). If I terminate the bot and then launch it from this bot_start.bat (that Windows also launch on pc startup) then simulating key presses again works. I couldn't seem to find any solution. What may be the solution?

I've tried, as I said, using different libs but none of them seemed to help.

Comment: Be more specific with "launched from pc startup". How have you configured the file to start during startup?

Comment: Are you sure the bot is running after the supposed automatic start-up? do other functions work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use pyautogui script in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909862/how-to-use-pyautogui-script-in-the-background)